# How to fix downloading of files in robcherry/docker-chromedriver docker

Tags: selenium, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, selenium-ide

I use Selenium IDE for file downloading test. The test works correctly when I ran it locally(downloads page opens and the list contains file that I downloaded), but it doesn't work in robcherry/docker-chromedriver docker. In the test I open chrome://downloads/ page after file downloading and this list is empty in docker.

I've added downloading path to a docker-compose file, but it doesn't help.

Here my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  chromedriver:
    image: robcherry/docker-chromedriver
    privileged: true
    restart: always
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Moscow
      - CHROMEDRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS=''
    volumes:
      - './module-selenium:/selenium'
      - './module-selenium/Downloads:/tmp/downloads'

  selenium-side-runner:
    image: bolotoff/selenium:v11
    volumes:
      - './module-selenium:/sides'
      - './out:/root/out'
```

Comment: Is there any error showing in chrome  ?

Comment: @AjayPandya No, just regular downloads page with empty list